# CodeAurora (CAF) tag naming meaning

Tags: android-source

What is the meaning of parts of tag (BuildID ) on CodeAurora ( on Qualcomm's MSM for Android repo).

The full list is here https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/release, but here are some examples:

- LA.UM.8.6.2.r2-01600-89xx.0
- LA.HB.1.1.8.c2-03700-8x96.0
- LA.AU.0.1.0.r2-02900-sa8155_gvmq.0
- LA.BR.1.3.6.c25-06800-8976.0

The **LA** part seems to be consistent, but I can't figure out the meaning of other parts like ( **UM, HB, AU, BR** ), or the versioning.
The last part **89xx** seems to refer to the hipset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I talked to a Qualcomm representative a while ago. This is what I could surmise:

```
LA = Linux Android  
UM = He didn't know either. Seems its just ramdom release naming, without some deeper meaning  
8.6.2.r2 = QCOM release version ( doesn't mean its Android 8 )  
01600 = release sub-version   
89xx  = chipset.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was told UM stands for "Unified Model"